# Link to non-image files in the File Manager?

Tags: ee2, file-manager

My client recently upgraded to EE2 from EE 1.7 and they lost the ability to directly get the link to non-image files (like PDFs) in the File Manager. They need this feature to insert into their email campaigns. Any idea how to get a direct link to an uploaded doc in EE2?

Screenshot, need link to Breast_Examination_Trainer_Final_UK.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EE 2.7+ non-image files are linked.

From the [EE changelog](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-0).

> All files regardless of type are now linked for viewing in the File Manager.

[image]